# Recognize a circle in color detection in OPEN CV PYTHON

Tags: python, opencv

I have a code here that detects LASER light but I'm experiencing problems in different light conditions. So I think I might solve it if I added a code that checks if that light is a circle.

The problem is I don't know how to apply it here. Here is what the laser light looks like in the mask.

I'm hoping that you can help me with my code.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) convert from bgr to hsv color space

    lower = np.array([0,0,255]) #range of laser light
    upper = np.array([255, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper) 
    maskcopy = mask.copy()

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(maskcopy, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 500,
                      param1 = 20, param2 = 10,
                      minRadius = 1, maxRadius = 3)
    _,cont,_ = cv2.findContours(maskcopy, cv2.RETR_LIST,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0,:]).astype('int')

        for(x,y,r) in circles:
            cv2.circle(frame, (x,y), r, (0,255,0),4)

    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use HoughCircle from https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html

Comment: if i were to use that, where should i put it in my code? Cause a while a go it was on my code. @Akhilesh

Comment: After `maskcopy = mask.copy()`, you can take a copy of `maskcopy` and can apply `houghcircle` of that copy.

Comment: ive edited my code up there but, im not sure with the values in the parameters. Mind if you check? :( @Akhilesh

Comment: use cv::findContours. Check for each contour whether minEnclosingCircle holds less than some relative amount of zero pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar once and the best solution for me was:

(I saved your image to my hard disk and made a sample code)

```
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread('laser.jpg')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
contour = area[0]
(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
radius = int(radius)
area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
circ = 4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2)
cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
print(circ)
```

So the idea is to find your contour with `cv2.findContours` (laser point) and enclosing circle to it so you can get the radius, then get the area with `cv2.contourArea` of your contour and check its circularity with the formula `circ = 4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2)`. The perfect citrcle would return the result of 1. The more it goes to 0 the less "circuar" your contour is (in pictures below). Hope it helps!

[image]

[image]

so your code should be something like this and it will return no error (tried it and it works)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #convert from bgr to hsv color space

        lower = np.array([0,0,255]) #range of laser light
        upper = np.array([255, 255, 255])

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper) 

        im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
        contour = area[0]
        (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
        radius = int(radius)
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        circ = 4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2)
        print(circ)
    except:
        pass

    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried applying it on the video, but i got tons of errors :(

Comment: But i get the idea.

Comment: I tried it and it worked...I have edited and posted my code implemented in yours

Comment: WOW SIR I THINK THIS MIGHT BE THE SOLUTION IVE BEEN LOOKING FOR. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Am glad I could help. Cheers!

Comment: i need your help once again, but this time with noises.

Comment: When I come home I will try to put the code together. (I posted the answer on your post with noises which I think should work if you try it yourself - selecting contour with limiting the size in area[i])

Comment: Ohhhh. I didn't notice that it was you. haha. Thank you! I'll look forward to it.

Comment: Btw if you find the answer adequate you should mark it as accepted so it could help others with similar problems. Cheers!

Comment: Done. Thank you SIr!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution with a different approach.

My idea was to create a circle with center in the center of the white region of the mask and with radius equal to half the width of the white region of the mask. Then I check how similar is this circle from the mask.

Here is the code:

```
white = np.where(mask>250) # you can also make it == 255
white = np.asarray(white)
minx = min(white[0])
maxx = max(white[0])
miny = min(white[1])
maxy = max(white[1])
radius = int((maxx-minx)/2)
cx = minx + radius
cy = miny + radius
black = mask.copy()
black[:,:]=0
cv2.circle(black, (cy,cx), radius, (255,255,255),-1)
diff = cv2.bitwise_xor(black, mask)
diffPercentage = len(diff>0)/diff.size
print (diffPercentage)
```

Then you have to come up with what percentage threshold is "similar" enough for you.

The code above was tested reading a mask from disk, but a video is just a sequence of images. Without your webcam input I cannot test the code with video, but it should work like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower = np.array([0,0,255]) #range of laser light
    upper = np.array([255, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper) 
    white = np.where(mask>250) # you can also make it == 255
    white = np.asarray(white)
    minx = min(white[0])
    maxx = max(white[0])
    miny = min(white[1])
    maxy = max(white[1])
    radius = int((maxx-minx)/2)
    cx = minx + radius
    cy = miny + radius
    black = mask.copy()
    black[:,:]=0
    cv2.circle(black, (cy,cx), radius, (255,255,255),-1)
    diff = cv2.bitwise_xor(black, mask)
    diffPercentage = len(diff>0)/diff.size
    print (diffPercentage)

    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cvw.imshow('diff', diff)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is this applicable to in a video Sir? And where will I place this?

Comment: Yes, a video is just a sequence of images. I will edit with the video part.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but i'm getting this error: "white = np.where(mask[:,:,0]>250) # you can also make it == 255
IndexError: too many indices for array"

Comment: I changed the code. try now.
What is really important is to understand the idea. This is just because I haven't tested your code with the hsl transformation and "inRange" function.  I don't have an example of your input to test it.

Comment: I'm still getting these error "IndexError: too many indices for array" in white = np.where(mask[:,;0]>250)

Comment: try ti check your mask shape with mask.shape
Can you save hsv and provide the image so that I can send you a code without error?

Comment: It works now, but can i just ask what is the diffPercentage?

Comment: Diff is difference.  Bitwise xor will tell you how different the image containing a perfect circle (black) is from your image (mask).  (maybe this will help you understand http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/bitwise-and-or-xor-and-not.html)

But this number by itself doesn't tell you if this is a huge difference or a small difference. So I divide by the image size. So, Diff Percentage is the percentage of pixels that are different in your image from the created image with perfect circle. This is a measure of how good your circle is.